# Terminal sudo dd error while making a bootable drive

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, sudo

So I have been trying to make a bootable Kali Linux USB drive for a while.

I am using the command:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/vanshyadav/Desktop/kali-linux-2018.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

It asks for my password once, and then gives me the error:

```
dd: /dev/disk2 bs=1m: Operation not supported
```

My drive looks like this:

[image]

I am following the steps in: [Making a Kali Bootable USB Drive](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install)

I unmount the disk using:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

It unmounts, but then it doesn't work.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to get the spaces correct in the command. Try cut-n-pasting the command from here:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/vanshyadav/Desktop/kali-linux-2018.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

Note that only regular spaces should be used.

You seem to have either forgotten the space, or used some other space-like character - therefore you get the weird error message where "/dev/disk2 bs=1m" is somehow used as the device name (i.e. the dd commands thinks that the bs parameter is somehow part of your device name).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I still do not understand what went wrong in my command, But thanks!